# Probability over a histogram

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are given the following region: $$B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}|0\le x \le 1, 0.5+2x \le y \le 2.5+2x\}$$

And I need to calculate the probability that $P(Y>2)$. We are told that the bivariate density is: $\frac{1}{2} 1_B(x,y)$ where $1_B(x,y)$ is the indicator function. I don't seem to understand why there is $\frac{1}{2}$ and not a 1. I know that $B$ spans a parallelogram. Next, I need to calculate the probability of $P(Y>2)$ where I believe this is the correct answer:

$$1-\int_{0.75}^{1} \int_{2.5}^{2.5x} \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{d}x\mathbb{d}y=0.78125$$ But I believe there must be an easier way that I cannot figure out. Can someone please explain why the bivariate density is as it and if there is an easier way to calculate $P(Y>2)$.

Comment: Easier way than that easy integral? Also write 2.5 as $\frac{5}{2}$ - it keeps things easier still.

Comment: Seriously, you've to integrate a constant and then something that is linear, these are __happy days__.

Comment: I know it's an easy integral, but either way it was the wrong answer and zolis answer is for me 'easier'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always helps if we picture the domain of integration:

[image]

Here, the red region is the domain of the density over which it takes the value $\frac12$ and over the blue framed region   $Y\le 2$.

(Why is there this $\frac12$? Because the area of the red region is $2$ and the integral of the joint density over the red region has to be $1$.)

The area of the blue framed triangle is $\frac9{16}$, the corresponding integral over the same triangle is $\frac9{32}$.

So,

$$P(Y>2)=1-\frac9{32}=\frac{23}{32}=0.71875.$$

(...and not $\color{red}{0.78125}$. Note that the mistake is not a consequence of erratic copying of a very similar number. The integral in the OP is wrong.)